# mysql WHERE IN array string / username

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Code:

```
$friendsArray = array("zac1987", "peter", "micellelimmeizheng1152013142");
$friendsArray2 = join(', ',$friendsArray);  
$query120 = "SELECT picturemedium FROM users WHERE username IN ('$friendsArray2')";
echo $query120;
```

This is the output :

```
SELECT picturemedium FROM users WHERE username IN ('zac1987, peter, micellelimmeizheng1152013142')
```

It fails because usernames are not wrapped by single quotes like 'zac1987', 'peter', 'mice...'. How can each username be wrapped with single quotes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's loop through each name one by one, escaping each.

I'm going to recommend that you use an actual MySQL escaping function rather than just wrapping quotes around, to ensure that the data actually goes into the query correctly. (Otherwise, if I entered a name like `It's me!`, the single quote would mess up the query.) I'm going to assume here that you're using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) (which you should!), but, if not, replace references to `PDO::quote` with `mysql_real_escape_string`.

```
foreach($friendsArray as $key => $friend) {
  $friendsArray[$key] = PDO::quote($friend);
}

$friendsArray2 = join(', ', $friendsArray);
```

Comment: I have tested mysql_real_escape_string, the output is still the same as 'zac1987, peter, micellelimmeizheng1152013142'

Comment: Yes, that should be the case here. What you need is `$friendsArray[$key] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($friend)."'";`.

Comment: @Michael: derp. Been a while since I used the standard MySQL functions xD Thanks for the catch :)

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to use PDO or other complicated solutions use implode function and you are all set.

```
$friendsArray  = array("zac1987", "peter", "micellelimmeizheng1152013142");
$friendsArray2 = "'" .implode("','", $friendsArray  ) . "'"; 
$query120      = "SELECT picturemedium FROM users WHERE username IN ( $friendsArray2 )";
echo $query120;
```

**Solution :** I just imploded your `$friendArray`  by  `','` that's it. plain and simple! and It's working.

**Output** :
`SELECT picturemedium FROM users WHERE username IN ('zac1987','peter','micellelimmeizheng1152013142')`

Comment: Very simple solution and in my case very timely, Thanks

Comment: Not very clean though & it might get a bit buggy, when the $friendsArray would be an empty array, the condition would end up beign IN ('') and that's definitely not desirable.

Answer (score 7):

Everything is easy if you only have numbers. But if you have strings you need to check for quotes and be careful.. If you don't want to use PDO or "mysql_real_escape_string", following code is OK. I tested, this works well.

```
$friendsArray = array("zac1987", "peter", "micellelimmeizheng1152013142");
$friendsArray2 = '"' . implode('","', $friendsArray) . '"';
$query120 = "SELECT picturemedium FROM users WHERE username IN ($friendsArray2)";
echo $query120;
```

Answer (score 5):

Found this question on Google and by doing so figured out a solution. Not sure how "proper" this solution is, but it worked for me.

```
    $friendsArray = array("zac1987", "peter", "micellelimmeizheng1152013142");
    $friendsArray2 = "'" . join(', ',$friendsArray) . "'";  
    $query120 = "SELECT picturemedium FROM users WHERE username IN ($friendsArray2)";
    echo $query120;
```

Comment: It has the same problem that is also presented above. Check Matchu's answer for real solution.

Comment: This appears to have a not add the middle single quotes. I believe what Jeremy meant to post is: $friendsArray2 = "'" . join("', '",$friendsArray) . "'";

Comment: The middle single quotes are missing (in case of numbers), should be `$friendsArray2 = "'" . join("', '",$friendsArray) . "'"; `

Answer (score 0):

Just had to do something very similar. This is a very simple way of doing it that I figured out after much headache.

```
$friendsArray = array("zac1987", "peter", "micellelimmeizheng1152013142");
$friendsArray2 = implode("','",$friendsArray);
```

this will add quotes in between each element in the array but not at the very beginning or the very end **Therefore:** $friendsArray2 = "zac1987','peter','micellelimmeizheng1152013142"
so now all you are missing is the single quote before the z in zac1987 and at the very end after 3142
to fix this just wrap $friendsArray2 in single quotes within your SELECT statement.

Its been tried, tested and true.

```
$query120 = "SELECT picturemedium FROM users WHERE username IN ('$friendsArray2')";
echo $query120;
```

**OUTPUT:** 
SELECT picturemedium FROM users WHERE username IN ('zac1987', 'peter', 'micellelimmeizheng1152013142')

Answer (score 0):

When using "IN" logical operator with strings, each string should be wrapped with quotation marks. This is not necessary if all values are numeric values.

```
$friendsArray = array("zac1987", "peter", "micellelimmeizheng1152013142");
$friendsArray2 = join("','",$friendsArray);  
$query120 = "SELECT picturemedium FROM users WHERE username IN ('{$friendsArray2}')";
echo $query120;
```

The output should be :

```
SELECT picturemedium FROM users WHERE username IN ('zac1987','peter','micellelimmeizheng1152013142')
```